# Aligning minipage with a tikz picture vertically simply with tabular and makecell

Tags: vertical-alignment, tikz-pic

Why does the top argument of minipage not effect the tikz content of the minipage, when it does effect simple text? Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{c|c}
\hline
\makecell[t]{
\begin{minipage}{.4\linewidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
\draw [thin,black,step=.5] (-.5,-.5) grid (.5,.5);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}}
&
\makecell[t]{
\begin{minipage}{.4\linewidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
\draw [thin,black, step=.5] (-1,-1) grid (1,1);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{c|c}
\hline
\makecell[t]{
Bla}
&
\makecell[t]{Bla bla \\ Bla bla} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image: output of the code]

What would be a simple solution within this frame, so with tabular and makecell? (If not possible of course otherwise) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is not clear what you like to obtain ... 
however, in the first table you nested `tikzpicture` which default baseline is at bottom of image and `minipage`s, which default baseline is on its middle of their heights and than encapsulate them to the `makecel`s which should be aligned to their top.

in the second table you have only `makecel`s aligned to their top.

to obtain the same result in the first table as it is in the second, you need to define the same position of `baseline` for all elements in table rows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
\hline
\makecell[t]{
\begin{minipage}[t]{.4\linewidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]
\draw [thin,black,step=.5] (-.5,-.5) grid (.5,.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
}
&
\makecell[t]{
\begin{minipage}[t]{.4\linewidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]
\draw [thin,black, step=.5] (-1,-1) grid (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
}
\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{c|c}
\hline
\makecell[t]{
Bla
}
&
\makecell[t]{
Bla bla \\ Bla bla
} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

the same result regarding to vertical position of cells' contents you obtain, if in the first table you remove `\makecell` and `\minipage` from table cells:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
\hline
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]
\draw [thin,black,step=.5] (-.5,-.5) grid (.5,.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
&
 \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]
\draw [thin,black, step=.5] (-1,-1) grid (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{c|c}
\hline
\makecell[t]{
Bla
}
&
\makecell[t]{
Bla bla \\ Bla bla
} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, this was exactly what I wanted to obtain, you understood it right. Thank you!